# Getting deleted adwords ads statistic via analytics

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I'm using analytics reporting api, to get ga:sessions,ga:bounces,ga:sessionDuration,ga:pageviews,ga:adClicks,ga:adCost,ga:impressions

for every ad, day and phrase. I found that adwords api don't return deleted or paused ads statitcs in reports, so you need to add that ads/campaigns/groups types in your report query. Now i see, that now all my results from adwords have analytics results. I suppose that the problem is the same, but dont see any ads/campaigns/groups dimensions.

How can i include deleted ads/campaigns/groups in my analytics report result?

Answer (score 1):

In your case I would consider Google [Data import](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3191589?hl=en) to get from the API the campaigns you require and then upload them manualy to GA. I haven't tried it for deleted campaigns but it might be possible. Also be advised that you cannot import past data if you don't have Google Analytics 360 enabled property